# Mac not opening .jar files

Tags: java, jar

I am trying to download a few programs that are written in java and have the extension of .jar.

I am having two types of failures:

1. The Java program launches (I can see it launched from applications) but nothing displays.
2. The Java Jar file "..." could not be launched. Check the console for possible error messages

This is the message I receive in the console:

I can't see an error being displayed but what do you think it is saying?

New Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1328)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(EventQueue.java:1303)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(SwingUtilities.java:1475)
    at com.epicbot.iIIiiIiiIIiIi.main(ihc:263)
    at com.epicbot.Boot.main(imc:404)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/eawt/QuitHandler
    at com.epicbot.IIIiIIiiiIIIi.ALLATORIxDEMO(dzb:459)
    at com.epicbot.iiIIIIiiiIIiI.run(ihc:315)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:764)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:711)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:89)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:734)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:199)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.apple.eawt.QuitHandler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
```

Comment: have you tried the jar on another computer, pref with another os? Did you make it yourself?

Comment: No, it is software off the internet. I know it is something to do with my computer because they are various different .jar files

Comment: The same result for each one.

Comment: well your best bet is to ask who ever made it, I'd check the version of JDK/JRE it requires and that I have it first. This probably is a bit off topic for here as we don't have the code or can't replicate the error

Comment: what happens if you run it on the console with java -jar <jarname> ?

Comment: So I went into the terminal and tried to open the file like this: java -jar <filename>

Comment: See the output in my edited post above

Comment: It says there are 16 more lines but I can't view them :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means, that your current java does not support the used methods in the jar.

These methods were removed:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-97C1D0BB-D5D3-4CAD-B17D-03A87A0AAF3B

Maybe you can try to install an older JRE and try again

See more informations about installing JRE here: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_mac.xml